# Focus textarea on mobile from click event using jQuery .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, focus, textarea

Alrighty, I'm stuck.

I'm trying desperately to focus on a text area programmatically from javascript (jQuery) on mobile. I did my research, and learned that the only way to bring the keyboard up with .focus() is to use a click event. So I made a click event. And it works when I click on the element, except I need to trigger this from a touchhold on a different element. So naturally, I tried .trigger() and .triggerHandler() on the element. But neither of those things work.

TLDR; I need to be able to hold on an element from a list, and after a time, a div will slide down with a textarea and the textarea gets focus (with keyboard).

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="quicknote" data-id="0">
    <span>New Note</span>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <textarea class="text"></textarea>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="left cancel">cancel</div>
        <div class="right finish">finish</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var holdThresh = 800;
    $(".row").on("touchstart", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var name = $(this).html();
    $(this).addClass("down");
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".quicknote").attr("data-id", id);
        $(".quicknote .name").html(name);
        $(".quicknote").addClass("open");
        $(".quicknote").trigger("click");
        e.preventDefault();
    }, holdThresh);

    $(this).one("touchend touchmove", function(event) {
        $(this).removeClass("down");
        clearTimeout(timer);
    })

    $(".quicknote .cancel").on("touchstart", function() {
        $(".quicknote").removeClass("open");
    })

    $(".quicknote").click(function(event) {
        $("textarea").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropogation();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! For anyone who finds this, here is my updated jQuery:

```
$(".row").on("touchstart", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var name = $(this).html();
    var go = true;
    var focus = false;

    $(this).addClass("down");

    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        go = false;


        $(".quicknote").attr("data-id", id);
        $(".quicknote .name").html(name);
        $(".note").val("");

        $(".quicknote, .overlay").addClass("open");
        focus = true;

        e.preventDefault();
    }, holdThresh);

    $(this).one("touchmove", function(event) {
        go = false;
        $(this).removeClass("down");
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    $(this).one("touchend", function() {
        if (go) window.location = "view.php?id=" + id;
        else {
            if (focus) {
                $(".note").focus();
                focus = false;
            }
            $(this).removeClass("down");
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    })
})
```

I'm not sure exactly why this works, but instead of triggering a click on a third element to then focus on the textarea, I set a flag "var focus", and based on some conditions, was able to focus the textarea from the touchend event. Hope this helps someone! :)